# Generic Parameterized superinterface declaration according to JLS

Tags: java, generics, interface, jls

According to JLS(§:9.1.3):

> Given a generic interface declaration I<F1,...,Fn> (n > 0), the direct superinterfaces of the parameterized interface type I<T1,...,Tn>, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type, are all types J<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>, where J<U1,...,Uk> is a direct superinterface of I<F1,...,Fn> and θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].

What is the meaning of `θ` as here? Can this be explained with some example expression for how `θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` holds?

Comment: I read θ as: "substitute formal type parameters with actual type arguments". What I have trouble with is the notation U₁ θ ("U-subscript-1-space-theta"). Interestingly, JLS 17 did away with all of this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.3